# reporte en blanco Crystal Report viewer, Porqué no se ve?

Tags: asp.net, aplicación-web, crystal-reports

Tengo un problema: Cuando llamo al reporte de CRV no lo visualiza,
el diseño del reporte tiene datos

Aquí un vistazo del código:

aspx:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Prueba Crystal"></asp:Label>
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
<CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
```

Page_Load

```
var reporte = new ReportDocument();
reporte.Load(Server.MapPath("/CrystalReport3.rpt")); CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reporte;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me ha pasado lo mismo, y resulta que tenes que tener los scripts de CrystalReports, la de tu version, en la misma carpeta de tu proyecto, estos scripts lo he encontrado en "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client" esa carpeta aspnet_client debes copiarlo a tu proyecto y ya deberia de funcionarte. Me paso en Visual Studio 2015 con Crystal Reports 2016

Comment: si, ese era el detalle. Gracias por comentar.